# Android Google Sign in and Save User Email Address in my database and Authentication for send user data and save on databse

Tags: android, authentication, google-oauth, google-signin

```
 boolean isLogin = false;
```

after user signed in successfully to my app:

```
 isLogin = true;
 String user_email_address = "example1@gmail.com";
```

now i save `user_email_address` to my database server by request POST: `https://example.com/insert_email.php?email=example1@gmail.com`

```
                      user tables

 -------id----------user_email_address-----------------
        1           example1@gmail.com
        2           example2@gmail.com
       ...          ..................
 ------------------------------------------------------
```

now, i want only logined users to insert and send comment for posts by form, in my android app `isLogin = true`, So:

```
 String user_comment = editText.getText().toString();
 https://example.com/insert_comment.php?email=example1@gmail.com&comment=user_comment
```

so on server:

```
 INSERT TO user_comment_table
 user_email, user_comment
 VALUES ( user_email, user_comment )
```

so

```
                      comment tables

 -------user_email----------user_comment-----------------
    example1@gmail.com     comment ......
    example1@gmail.com     comment ......
       ...          ..................
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, i need **authorization and Authentication** for this:

```
 https://example.com/insert_comment.php?email=example1@gmail.com&comment=user_comment
```

Comment: You can use an ID token from Google Sign-In for authorization (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html), but my recommendation would be to go with Firebase Auth if you can: it will handle multiple types of authentication and session management, and the provides a backend and UI for you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: @StevenSoneff i need save user emails and save comments and likes for any emails... firebase provide this?

Comment: Ya, it comes with authenticated file/image storage and a real-time database: https://firebase.google.com/features/

Answer (score 2):

You should read this post (authentication on your Android app/user to your server). This should answer the questions you have.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html